# Having trouble to decode a JSON

Tags: php, json

I guess there may be a hidden character inside.

JSON data:

The following response i am getting using [this URL](http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=&series_id=NG.N3010US3.A)

> {"request":{"command":"series","series_id":"ng.n3010us3.a"},"data":{"error":"No api_key. For key registration, documentation, and examples see http://www.eia.gov/developer/"}}

What I did:

1. Use file_get_contents fetch the data from the URL
2. use json_decode($rawjson,TRUE); to make it as an array. -> ERROR

the json_last_error_message shows 'Syntax Error'

I'm trying to find which character is causing the problem.

Comment: Cannot duplicate. Are you certain that's the data that your script is processing?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ indicates your JSON is perfect. Tried using json_decode and that works wonderfully well. Include your code here and in your code, right before `json_decode($rawjson, true);`, do `echo $rawjson;` and include whatever is echoed out in your post as well.

Comment: @zedfoxus echo $rawjson; shows exactly the same. If you copy and paste my data, there wont be any problem with the decode. But when use file_get_contents, json_decode won't work

Comment: Look at the very nice solution provided by Alex. Byte order mark sequence is received along with the JSON when you do file_get_contents. That's why you are having troubles. Alex's solution will get you going. If you continue to have troubles, feel free to post a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, the response includes a `BOM` sequence.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom) more about byte-order-mark.

You can remove it like so:

```
$j = file_get_contents("http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=&series_id=NG.N3010US3.A");

$o = json_decode(remove_bom($j));

var_dump($o);


function remove_bom($string)
{
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $sring;
}
```